# Commanding in MVVM (WPF)--how to return a bool value?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have 2 application, say app1 & app2
I am hosting app2 into app1. 
I have 1 tool bar, hosted app1 view and status bar on app1.
Now I binding commands on tool bar button those command are implemented in app1 view.
Now app1 want to know whether operation is performed or not so app2 need to notify app1 that this operation is performed and update status bar, 
but how can I return bool value using command?
figure explaining scenario
[image]

Comment: Does your app2 close after it has completed its job? Or will it remain open?

Comment: You have control above both apps source code? Both in C# .NET?

Comment: yes I can change source code of both the app. app1 is wpf and app2 is win form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to define a parameter class with a `Result` property which would be set in the execution code and then retrieved in the invocation code, very much like it's done with events (after all commands are primarily used as an alternative to events in WPF UI design).

Comment: Yes I also was thinking about this. Instead of creating property in new class I can create that property where that command is defined in app2.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [anonymous pipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or a [named pipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
For local execution, the ***anonymous pipe*** is recommended, where as the ***named pipe*** allows cross-computer communication in a network.

You execution order should look like the following:

1. APP1 creates a "server instance" of the pipe
2. APP1 starts APP2 via your command
3. APP2 performs its task
4. APP2 connects to APP1 via the **anonymous pipe** as client
5. APP2 sends its result via the pipe to APP1

**Please note:**

- APP1 should always be aware of the fact, that APP2 may **NOT** return anything via the pipe. So APP1 shouldn't be in an inconsistent state after starting APP2
- After APP1 receives the result of APP2, the APP1 should close the server-side of the pipe

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this will work for you or not.  Its something i found on [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28453/WPF-Commands-Return-Value).  The idea is that you have a type of icommand that has an additional property and an event.  This extra property is your return type.  Before you run your functionality, you attach a listener to the new event in your command so that when your functionality is done, you can respond accordingly.

Another idea would be to do something like prism or MVVMLight do.  They have mechanisms for passing events around the system.  MVVMLight calls theirs an Event Aggregator.

I have used both approaches in the past.  The event aggregator one is nice in my opinion, because it can easily solve severa other communication problems.  Just be careful not to use it too much.  It can certainly be a crutch.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question correctly.

Comment: In fairness the question wasn't very clear either, [Interprocess Communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx) is not a trivial subject.

Comment: Yeah it looked like he was looking for a multi app MEF thing to me at first.  Its cool, its not like there is really any drawnack to misunderstanding the question. I could have answered that quesrion too, but we all have to sleep some time.